# How can I Periodically Insert Data in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I want to periodically insert data from S3 (or other fonts) into Amazon Redshift, i.e., when data is added to my S3 bucket, I want an option to add it automatically to my Amazon Redshift cluster.

Comment: what do you mean by other fonts? How S3 is going to get the data ?

Comment: @AmithJayasekara other fonts like mysql databases

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method for doing this is to establish a trigger that fire every time a file is created in a part of a bucket.  This trigger creates an event that initiates a Lambda function that issues the desired SQL to Redshift.  (Or if the work that is needed in Redshift is complex or long running I will use a step function but this is rare.)

Example setups for this:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html
https://64lines.medium.com/building-a-aws-lambda-function-to-run-aws-redshift-sql-scripts-in-python-7468b7c2fdea

I'd start simple if you can and work up to Redshift Data API and Step functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate the insertion of data from S3 with a scheduled Lambda that triggers periodically. This might be a better solution than invoking a Lambda on every object upload, especially if you are receiving lots of files continuously.